# Why does Clojure defmulti dispatch function receive 0 args?

Tags: clojure

Begin Edit:

Mea Culpa! I apologize.

I was running this in the cake repl at Clojure 1.2.1, and it honestly did not work. Now it does after exiting cake repl and a cake compile, and it also works at 1.3.0.

End Edit:

In the following: my dispatch function is being passed zero args, but I cannot figure out why. I've tested the dispatch function, and it does what it is supposed to. I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
(defrecord AcctInfo [acct-type int-val cur-bal])
(def acct-info (AcctInfo. \C 0.02 100.00))
ba1-app=> acct-info
ba1_app.AcctInfo{:acct-type \C, :int-val 0.02, :cur-bal 100.0}

(defn get-int-calc-tag [acct-type]
    (cond   (= acct-type \C) :checking
            (= acct-type \S) :savings
            (= acct-type \M) :moneym
            :else            :unknown))

(defmulti calc-int (fn [acct-info] (get-int-calc-tag (:acct-type acct-info))))

(defmethod calc-int :checking [acct-info] (* (:cur-bal acct-info) (:int-val acct-info)))

ba1-app=> (get-int-calc-tag (:acct-type acct-info))
:checking

ba1-app=> (calc-int acct-info)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: ba1-app$get-int-calc-tag
```

Comment: Copying and pasting your code as given into a clean repl does not produce the error you report. It runs and returns the value 2.0.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and got the error, so perhaps this is Clojure version related? Tried again with Clojure 1.3, and it worked.

Comment: tried in a 1.2.1 repl, works fine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem could perhaps be related to the undocumented `defonce`-like behavior of `defmulti`.

If you reload a namespace that contains a `(defmulti foo ...)` form then that `defmulti` won't be updated. This often means that the dispatch function will not be updated but all method implementations (in the same namespace) will. (`defmulti foo ...)` does nothing if the `foo` var is already bound to a value.

To fix this in a REPL, remove the multimethod var `(ns-unmap 'the.ns 'the-multimethod)` and then reload the namespace `(require 'the.ns :reload)`.

To prevent this problem you can define the dispatch function separately and pass its var to `defmulti` like this:

```
(defn foo-dispatch [...]
  ...)

(defmulti foo #'foo-dispatch)
```

When the code looks like this it's enough to reload the namespace if you make a change to `foo-dispatch`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is a big help.